# Conditional Join in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 variables which `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3` which are based on user input. Whose value will be either 1 or 0.

And the tables are

- `userlist` (userid, name, filtercount1, filtercount2, filtercount3)`
- `filtertable1` (id, filtercount1)
- `filtertable2` (id, filtercount1)
- `filtertable3` (id, filtercount1)

Now I want to write a query such that:

- if filter1 = 1 then, inner join user to filtertable1
- if filter2 = 1 then, inner join user to filtertable2
- if filter3 = 1 then, innerjoin user to filtertable3.

Now How do I conditionally add innerjoin `conjunctively` to the above scenario, or is there any other way for the above problem statement.

I've tried the below solution,

```
Select * 
from 
    users
left join 
    filtertable1 on users.filtercount1 = filtertable1.filtercount1 
                 and filter1 = 1
left join 
    filtertable2 on users.filtercount2 = filtertable3.filtercount2 
                 and filter2 = 1
left join 
    filtertable3 on users.filtercount3 = filtertable3.filtercount3 
                 and filter3 = 1
```

But I don't want to use left join. And is it such that if data is larger(20000 rows) than left join will take more time than inner join for the above scenario.

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? The situation as described is kinda unusual and I think you've made a design-mistake earlier-on which led you into now having _this_ problem. Also, what does `filtercount` represent? Is `users` a `VIEW` or a `BASE TABLE`?

Comment: If `filter1`, `filter2`, and `filter3` are variables, why don't they have the `@` prefix?

Comment: Should the filters be applied conjunctively or disjunctively? That's an important detail...

Comment: It should be applied conjunctively

Comment: Why do you have 3 separate tables doing the same thing anyway? Shouldn't they all be one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left join` is fine.  But you can also use `exists`:

```
Select u.*
from users u
where (u.filter1 = 1 and
       exists (select 1 from filtertable1 ft where u.filtercount1 = ft.filtercount1)
      ) or
      (u.filter2 = 1 and
       exists (select 1 from filtertable2 ft where u.filtercount2 = ft.filtercount1)
      ) or
      (u.filter3 = 1 and
       exists (select 1 from filtertable3 ft where u.filtercount3 = ft.filtercount1)
      ) ;
```

Note:  I'm not sure if you want `and` or `or` between the conditions.  With `and` the logic would be slightly different.

Comment: What if filter1 and filter2 both are 1 and filter3 is 0, in doubt if this query will work or not?

Comment: @beingyogi You actually left that undefined yourself. You haven't said if `filter1`, `filter2` and `filter3` should be applied conjunctively (`AND`) or disjunctively (`OR`).

Comment: @Dai it should be applied conjunctively (AND) .

Comment: @beingyogi . . . I *think* you can just replace the `or` with `and` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional filtering should not be done inside a query, because it results in suboptimal query execution plans.

- Instead, for each "query shape" *use a different query*... though this now means having to either use many `IF` branches to hold each different query or use Dynamic-SQL.

### Dynamic SQL

- Rather than putting *the entire query* (including any `GROUP BY` and aggregations and other predicates) in Dynamic SQL instead use Dynamic-SQL to build **only** a `TABLE`-variable containing only primary-keys, - then use that table-variable in the final non-dynamic output query.

  - This approach means you can also use it in other queries in the same procedure without re-running the search. Use `sp_executesql` to INSERT into a table-variable in an outer-scope.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @filter1 bit = 0;
DECLARE @filter2 bit = 0;
DECLARE @filter3 bit = 0;

DECLARE @userIds TABLE ( userId int PRIMARY KEY );

DECLARE @q varchar(max) = 'SELECT UserId FROM dbo.Users AS u';
IF @filter1 = 1
BEGIN
    @q = @q + 'INNER JOIN filtertable1 AS f1 ON u.filtercount1 = f1.filtercount1 ';
END

IF @filter2 = 1
BEGIN
    @q = @q + 'INNER JOIN filtertable2 AS f2 ON u.filtercount2 = f2.filtercount2' ;
END

IF @filter2 = 1
BEGIN
    @q = @q + 'INNER JOIN filtertable3 AS f3 ON u.filtercount3 = f3.filtercount3 ';
END

@q = 'INSERT INTO @userIds ' + @q;

EXEC sp_executesql @q;

----

SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    users AS u
    INNER JOIN @userIds AS f ON f.UserId = u.UserId
```

### Filtering in-place

In this particular scenario, you don't *need* Dynamic SQL, you can reduce the `@userIds` list in-place, like so:

```
DECLARE @filter1 bit = 0;
DECLARE @filter2 bit = 0;
DECLARE @filter3 bit = 0;

DECLARE @userIdsSoFar TABLE ( userId int PRIMARY KEY );

INSERT INTO @userIdsSoFar ( userId )
SELECT
    u.userId
FROM
    users AS u;

IF @filter1 = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @userIdsSoFar
    WHERE userId NOT IN (
        SELECT
            u.userId
        FROM
            users AS u
            INNER JOIN filtertable1 AS f1 ON u.filtercount1 = f1.filtercount1
    )
END

IF @filter2 = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @userIdsSoFar
    WHERE userId NOT IN (
        SELECT
            u.userId
        FROM
            users AS u
            INNER JOIN filtertable2 AS f2 ON u.filtercount2 = f2.filtercount2
    )
END

IF @filter3 = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @userIdsSoFar
    WHERE userId NOT IN (
        SELECT
            u.userId
        FROM
            users AS u
            INNER JOIN filtertable3 AS f3 ON u.filtercount3 = f3.filtercount3
    )
END

----

SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    users AS u
    INNER JOIN @userIdsSoFar AS f ON f.UserId = u.UserId
```